# Como consigo que reconozca estos 4 Caracteres entre comiilas "[GS]" como SQL y no como PhP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

En la siguiente consulta de php pero no me permite quitar esto **[GS]** eso esta entre corchetes dentro de la tabla como registro (NOTA: Abajo dejo una pequeña Foto Captura SQL de mi duda agradezco respuestas. Creo que la imagen explica mejor.)

```
$result3 = mssql_query(' UPDATE Ps_GameData.dbo.Chars 
SET CharName = replace (CharName,\'' **[GS]** '\' ,'' ) ');
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected [ in line 60`

Quiero que quite "**[GS]**" y deje vacío el nombre.

Ejemplo:

La consulta SQL:

```
UPDATE PS_GameData.dbo.Chars SET CharName = replace (CharName, '**[GS]**' ,'')
```

Obtiene este resultado:

```
[GS]Juan
```

En este caso, quiero que quede "Juan" simplemente sin el contenido dentro del corchete.

La consulta SQL funciona bien pero necesito adaptar esta funcionalidad usando php.

Ejemplo:

```
$result3 = mssql_query(' UPDATE Ps_GameData.dbo.Chars 
SET CharName = \'**[**\'+\'**GS**\'+\'**]**\' + CharName ');
```

Funciona excelente, pero quiero ahora quitarlo y no hallo la manera se que se usa remplace pero no ubico la configuracion de caracteres para que el corchete sea parte de la consulta SQL php

Deseo eliminar el caracter **[** antes de **GS** como seria dicha síntesis:

```
    $result3 = mssql_query("UPDATE Ps_GameData.dbo.Chars 
    SET  CharName = replace (CharName,'\'[ '\','')
```

[image: descripcion en notepad++]

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas una combinación de comillas simples y dobles? Estás encapsulando una cadena que contiene comillas simples con comillas simples, usa comillas dobles en su lugar y te quitarás de problemas de `\'`. Aparte de eso, estás haciéndolo mal, no sería `\''`, sino `'\'`, por eso no funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás poniendo el escape del carácter en la comilla equivocada. En lugar de ser así `\''`:

```
$result3 = mssql_query(' UPDATE Ps_GameData.dbo.Chars SET CharName = replace (CharName,\'' [GS] '\' ,'' ) ');
```

debería ser de este otro modo `'\'`:

```
$result3 = mssql_query(' UPDATE Ps_GameData.dbo.Chars SET CharName = replace (CharName,'\' [GS] '\' ,'' ) ');
```

Puedes ver que el editor de código colorea la cadena correctamente ahora.

---

Aparte, como te pongo en un comentario, podrías hacerlo todo más sencillo si en lugar de encapsular todo con comillas simples, usaras una combinación de comillas simples y dobles, así no te tendrías que preocupar por escapar cosas dentro de tu cadena:

```
$result3 = mssql_query(" UPDATE Ps_GameData.dbo.Chars SET CharName = replace (CharName, '[GS]' ,'' ) ");
```

Comment: Gracias exactamente lo que buscaba bro Alvaro Montoro alguna forma de calificar tu ayuda?

Comment: Si esta respuesta solucionó tu pregunta, acéptada pulsando en el tick que hay en la esquina superior izquierda de la respuesta.